# use of random() and randomize() in C++

Tags: c++

Please explain me how the code i am providing gives the output as :

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iostream.h>

int main()
{
   randomize();
   int Num, Rndnum; 
   cin >> Num;

   Rndnum = random(Num) + 7;
   for (int N =1; N<=Rndnum; N++)
         cout << N <<"";
}
```

Please explain me this code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you are taking an input `Num` from the user and passing that to a `random()` function. You are then taking the returned value from that function and adding 7 to it and assigning it to `Rndnum`. Finally you are looping through from 1 to the `Rndnum` and printing of each of those numbers (1, 2, ...., Rndnum).

In the case of printing out 1 - 11 you must have gotten a return value of 4 from `random(Num)`.

Comment: Ya that i understood but please tell me why the output is from 1 to 11

Comment: Like I said the loop at the bottom prints out all of the numbers from 1 to `Rndnum` so `Rndnum` in this case must equal 11. This means that `random(Num)` returned the number `4` (since 4+7=11).

Answer (score 0):

since I cannot see neither the function `randomize()` nor `random()`, I cannot tell you what they do but in this case the function call `random(Num)` gives back a 4, so `Rndum` adds up to 11. 
Lastly, the for-loop repeates 11 (1 to inclusively 11) times and each time the output is the counter `N` itself.
So depending on what `random` does to your variable `Num` the number of iterations of your loop change.

Hope that helps!

P.S. If you want to look into random numbers in c++, take a look here
[C++ rand](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/)